# Java --version command not recognizing jenv installed version. How can I fix this?

Tags: java, jenv

`java --version` command is not working after setting the version using `jenv`.

```
➜  ~ java --version
Usage: java [options] <mainclass> [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [options] -jar <jarfile> [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)
   or  java [options] -m <module>[/<mainclass>] [args...]
       java [options] --module <module>[/<mainclass>] [args...]
           (to execute the main class in a module)
   or  java [options] <sourcefile> [args]
           (to execute a single source-file program)
...
...
```

Below is the output I am getting for the usual `jenv` commands.

output of `jenv doctor`

```
➜  ~ jenv doctor
[OK]    JAVA_HOME variable probably set by jenv PROMPT
[OK]    Java binaries in path are jenv shims
[OK]    Jenv is correctly loaded
```

output of `cat ~/.zshrc | grep jenv`

```
➜  ~ cat ~/.zshrc | grep jenv
## Initializations for jenv
export PATH="$HOME/.jenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(jenv init -)"
export JAVA_HOME="$(jenv prefix)"
```

the output of some of the other commands that are usually used to understand the `jenv` environment

```
➜  ~ eval "$(jenv init -)"
➜  ~
➜  ~ jenv enable-plugin export
export plugin already enabled
➜  ~ jenv version
system (set by /Users/my_username/.jenv/version)
```

This has been incredibly frustrating. Any help would be appreciated. I have tried restarting my machine, reinstalling `jenv` etc., but no luck.

I have reinstalled `jenv`, tried restarting my machine, and tried to change the java version using `jenv global version`. No luck.

Comment: The correct command is `java -version` you added an extra `-`.

Comment: @user16320675 As of which version? Because it isn't supported by the version OP is using.

Comment: I tried `--version` `-version` and `-v` nothing worked

Comment: @ElliottFrisch The option `--version` was introduced in Java 9 (e.g. see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/java.htm#JSWOR624)

Comment: The output mentioned modules so it has to be Java 9+

Comment: Try `which java`